# Mysql date format in codeigniter model

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, date, codeigniter-3

I am using this syntax for date format in  codeigniter model

```
 $this->db->where(DATE_FORMAT(`RD`.`CREATED_TS =`,'%Y-%m-%d'), $from);
 $this->db->where(DATE_FORMAT(`RD`.`CREATED_TS =`,'%Y-%m-%d'), $to);
```

but it returns this error

```
Message: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, string given
```

and when am executing the query the query returns as below the CREATED_TS is represented by 0 how can i assign the name for CREATED_TS

```
SELECT `EP`.`EMPLOYEE_ID`, `EP`.`EMPLOYEENAME`, `RD`.`RETAILER_CODE`, `RD`.`RETAILER_NAME`, `RD`.`AREA_NAME`, `RD`.`LOCALITY`, `RD`.`DISTRICT`, `RD`.`STATE`, `RD`.`PINCODE`, `RD`.`MOBILE_NUMBER`, `P`.`PATCH`, `RD`.`CREATED_TS` FROM `PATIENT_PRIMARY` `P` LEFT JOIN `RETAILER_DETAILS` `RD` ON `P`.`PATIENT_CODE` = `RD`.`PATIENT_CODE` LEFT JOIN `HHCL_EMPLOYEEMASTER`.`EMPLOYEE_PRIMARY` `EP` ON `P`.`CREATED_BY` = `EP`.`EMPLOYEE_ID` WHERE `P`.`CREATED_BY` NOT IN(7777) AND `RD`.`MOBILE_NUMBER` NOT IN(8985180306) AND 0 IS NULL AND 0 IS NULL
```

Comment: use php date format date('Y-m-d', strtotime("your-date"));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [**`DATE_CREATE`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-create.php) to format string date will solve this issue

```
 $this->db->where(DATE_FORMAT(DATE_CREATE(`RD`.`CREATED_TS`), 'Y-m-d'), $from);
 $this->db->where(DATE_FORMAT(DATE_CREATE(`RD`.`CREATED_TS`), 'Y-m-d'), $to);
```

> **Note:** This will produce `=` in where, if you want to use `BETWEEN` then place `>=` and `<=` accordingly

---

**Edit 01**

```
$this->db->where("DATE(RD.CREATED_TS)", DATE_FORMAT(DATE_CREATE($from), 'Y-m-d'));
$this->db->where("DATE(RD.CREATED_TS)", DATE_FORMAT(DATE_CREATE($to), 'Y-m-d'));
```

Comment: SELECT `EP`.`EMPLOYEE_ID`, `EP`.`EMPLOYEENAME`, `RD`.`RETAILER_CODE`, `RD`.`RETAILER_NAME`, `RD`.`AREA_NAME`, `RD`.`LOCALITY`, `RD`.`DISTRICT`, `RD`.`STATE`, `RD`.`PINCODE`, `RD`.`MOBILE_NUMBER`, `P`.`PATCH`, `RD`.`CREATED_TS` FROM `PATIENT_PRIMARY` `P` LEFT JOIN `RETAILER_DETAILS` `RD` ON `P`.`PATIENT_CODE` = `RD`.`PATIENT_CODE` LEFT JOIN `HHCL_EMPLOYEEMASTER`.`EMPLOYEE_PRIMARY` `EP` ON `P`.`CREATED_BY` = `EP`.`EMPLOYEE_ID` WHERE `P`.`CREATED_BY` NOT IN(7777) AND `RD`.`MOBILE_NUMBER` NOT IN(8985180306) AND `2018-03-14` IS NULL AND `2018-03-14` IS NULL

Comment: The column name is overridden with the date

Comment: in the column ``RD`.`CREATED_TS`` how dates are written ? show me example

Comment: In this way the dates are stored in RD.CREATED_TS column 2018-03-13 16:38:23

Comment: @SairamDuggi check now

Comment: Thanks @Abulla Nilam

Comment: np. happy to help :)

Answer (score -1):

You should declare **RD.CREATED_TS** using **as** and use them in DATE_FORMAT() function.

**You should do like this :**

```
$this->db->select("RD.CREATED_TS as created_ts");
$this->db->where(DATE_FORMAT('created_ts','%Y-%m-%d'), $from);
$this->db->where(DATE_FORMAT('created_ts','%Y-%m-%d'), $to);
```

Comment please if am i wrong.

Comment: No its returns NULL @Dhaval